# Script google error

Tags: javascript, xml

I get this error in my code:

> TypeError: Cannot find function substring in object 2066. (line 50, archive "Code")

This one below to be more specific:

`if (InputString.substring(0, 10) = "[DUPLIKAT ")`

Here is the script:

```js
function onOpen() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var entries =
      [
       // {name : "Längen berechnen", functionName : "CountCellLength"}
      ];
  
  spreadsheet.addMenu("Script Menü", entries);
};


function CountCellLength()
{
  
  /*
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ssCurrent = ss.getActiveSheet();
  
  if (ss.getActiveSheet().getName() != "Duplikate")
  {
    Browser.msgBox("Not designed for this sheet.");
    return;
  }

  var RowCount = ss.getLastRow();
  var CurrentRow = ss.getActiveCell().getRow();
  var cellValue;


  for (var i = 5; i < RowCount; i++) {
    cellValue = ssCurrent.getRange(i, 2, 1, 1).getValue();
    
        ssCurrent.getRange(i, 5).setValue(cellValue.length);
  }
  
  */
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Duplikate");
  var RowCount= ss.getLastRow();
  var InputRange = ss.getRange(5, 2, RowCount-4);
  var data = InputRange.getValues();
  var InputString, OutputString;
  var StringNumber;

  
  for (var i = 0; i < RowCount; i++) {
    
    InputString = data[i][0];
    
    if (InputString.substring(0, 10) = "[DUPLIKAT ")
    {
      OutputString = ""
    } else {
      OutputString = InputString
    }
    
    OutputString = OutputString.replace("(nl)", "");
    OutputString = OutputString.replace("(nb)", "");
    OutputString = OutputString.replace("<$06><$00>", "HELDNAME");
    OutputString = OutputString.replace("<$06><$01>", "BURGNAME");
    OutputString = OutputString.replace("<$07><$00><$02>", "XXX");
    
    /*
    for (var j = 0 ; j < 256 ; j++)
    {
      StringNumber = j.toString(16);
      
      if (StringNumber.length == 1)
      {
        StringNumber = "0" + StringNumber.toUpperCase();
      } else {
        StringNumber = StringNumber.toUpperCase();
      }
      OutputString = OutputString.replace("<$" + StringNumber + ">", "");
    }
*/
    //ss.getRange(i+5, 5).setValue(OutputString);
    ss.getRange(i+5, 6).setValue(OutputString.length);
    
  }
}


function InsertDuplicate()
{
  //Festlegen des aktuellen Spreadsheets
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  //Das derzeit geöffnete Sheet
  var ssCurrent = ss.getActiveSheet();
  //Unser Duplikat Sheet
  var ssDuplicates = ss.getSheetByName("Duplikate");
  //Andere Variabeln
  var DuplicateInfo, DuplicateIndexRow, DuplicateNumber;
  var DuplicateRow;

  
  //Festlegen der Position, in der wir uns befinden
  ssCurrentColumn = ssCurrent.getActiveCell().getColumn();
  
  //Wenn wir nicht in der ersten Spalte sind, verlassen wir die Funktion
  if (ssCurrentColumn != 1) {
    return;
  }
  
  //Zelleninhalt abrufen und auf DUPLIKAT püfen
  DuplicateInfo = ssCurrent.getActiveCell().getValue();
  if (DuplicateInfo.substring(10, 0) == "DUPLIKAT: ")
  { DuplicateIndexRow = DuplicateInfo.substring(14,10);
  } else {
    return;
  }
  

  DuplicateRow = ssDuplicates.getRange(DuplicateIndexRow, 7).getValue();
  
  Browser.msgBox(DuplicateRow);
  //Browser.msgBox(DuplicateRow);
  
  
  

  //Browser.msgBox("End reached!!!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is exactly as the error says. 
Your InputString variable is not what you think it is. Its a javascript [object](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp)  instead of a string.

Javascript works with objects and thus (weird at first) a string is also an object with so called methods (helper functions for that specific object type). A String object does contain a substring method, but an "object object" does not.

In order to help you solve this problem..
Can you log that variable to the console using console.log, so we have an idea what the variable contains?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your anwser!
I'm using the code directly in the script.google.
is that possible log that variable from there?
Sorry, i'm newbie :/

Answer (score 0):

Two problems I can see but they might not be the only issues:

`substring` will only work on strings, so if your value read from the spreadsheet is a number, then it will fail as you can see.

To coerce the value to a string, you could instead of:

```
InputString = data[i][0];
```

use:

```
InputString = data[i][0] + '';
```

Concatentating with an empty string will force numbers the resulting value to be a string.

Secondly:

`if (InputString.substring(0, 10) = "[DUPLIKAT ")` is not the correct use of the equals sign:

- Single equals, `=` is **assignment**, for example when you are placing a value into a variable
- Double equals, `==` is **equality**, for comparing two values

In the above `if` statement, you are looking to compare two values to see if the one on the left is equal to `"[DUPLIKAT "`. Therefore you need two equals (three equals is a subject to take a look at if you wish...):

`if (InputString.substring(0, 10) == "[DUPLIKAT ")`

Comment: Thank you so much, Seems to work parcially
Now its showing the follow error

TypeError: Cannot read property "0" from undefined.
Line 48 = InputString = data[i][0] + '';